# what the Time Complexity of T(n) = 2T(n/2) +O(1)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

i want to know what the Time Complexity of my recursion method :
 T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)
i saw a result that says it is O(n) but i don't know why , i solved it like this :

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1
T(n-1) = 4T(n-1/4) + 3
 T(n-2) = 8T(n-2/8) + 7
......  …………..  ..
T(n) = 2^n+1 T (n/2^n+1) + (2^n+1 - 1)
```

Comment: This should help https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-complexity-of-T-n-2T-n-2-+-C-using-recurrence-equations

Comment: [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). Your expansion is incorrect in the sense that the exponent of `2` is *not* `n`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i know it is not correct , i am still a little confused about how to find t(n-n)

Comment: You should think about what you're actually doing in every step. `T(n)` is in terms of `T(n/2)`, so `T(n-1)` is not relevant. You're also substituting in a way that doesn't make sense - you have `T(n-1) = 2T((n-1)/2) + O(1)`, but then you substitute `T(n)` in there instead of `T((n-1)/2)`. You're also going down to `T(1)` when you should just be calculating `T(n)` (substitute `T(n/2)` in `T(n)`, not the other way around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have got the wrong idea about recursive relations. You can think as follows:

If T(n) represents the value of function T() at input = n then the relation says that output is one more double the value at half of the current input. So for input = n-1 output i.e. T(n-1) will be one more than double the value at half of this input, that is T(n-1) = 2*T((n-1)/2) + 1

The above kind of recursive relation should be solved as answered by Yves Daoust. For more examples on recursive relations, you can refer [this](http://discretetext.oscarlevin.com/dmoi/sec_recurrence.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `n=2^m`, which allows you to write

```
T(2^m)=2T(2^(m-1))+O(1)
```

or by denoting `S(m):= T(2^m)`,

```
S(m)=2 S(m-1) + O(1),

2^m S(m)=2 2^(m-1)S(m-1) + 2^(m-1) O(1)
```

and finally,

```
R(m) = R(m-1) + 2^(m-1) O(1).
```

Now by induction,

```
R(m) = R(0) + (2^m-1) O(1),

T(n) = S(m) = 2^(1-m) T(2^m) + (2 - 2^(m-1)) O(1) = 2/n T(n) + (2 - n/2) O(1).
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of rules that you might need to remember. If you can remember these easy rules then Master Theorem is very easy to solve recurrence equations. The following are the basic rules which needs to be remembered

```
case 1) If n^(log b base a) << f(n) then T(n) = f(n)
case 2) If n^(log b base a) = f(n) then T(n) = f(n) * log n
case 3) 1) If n^(log b base a) >> f(n) then T(n) = n^(log b base a)
```

Now, lets solve the recurrence using the above equations.

```
a = 2, b = 2, f(n) = O(1)
n^(log b base a) = n = O(n)
```

This is case 3) in the above equations. Hence T(n) = n^(log b base a) = O(n).